# How to $http post to the datastore

Tags: python, angularjs, google-app-engine

I am building a simple site using python, jinja2 and specifically on one page I'm using angularjs. I'm relatively new to jinja2 and angular. I need help posting to the GAE datastore and displaying the comment dynamically without reloading the page (angular). Here's handler part in the main.py:

```
class expHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    title="Colin_MK: Experience"
    recommendations = Recommendation.query()
    self.response.out.write(json.dumps([rec.to_dict() for rec in recommendations]))
    template_vars = {'title': title, 'recommendations': recommendations}
    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/exp.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_vars))

def post(self):
    r = json.loads(self.request.body)

    new_comment = Recommendation(comment=r['comment'])
    new_comment.put()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the desired result?

Comment: @jkalden thanks for responding. The desired result is populating 'comments' on a page dynamically without refreshing (similar to facebook) and at the same time storing the data in the datastore. Do you need to look at any other files?html? I seem to be able to fetch the data from the datastore with json.dumps but it's not linking with the jinja2 template